# SQLite and SQLite Net Extensions - where's the Foreign Key Constraint?

Tags: sqlite, foreign-key-relationship, sqlite-net-extensions

I am just confused here (maybe I am missing something?)

I've been pulling my hair out trying to work out why on earth my SQLite DB created using the sample on [sqlite-net-extensions](https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions) is **not creating foreign key relationships**

Answer (score 3):

**I do really truly appreciate** the fact that people in the community take the time to package up, document, release and maintain their **awesome code** for the rest of us - I really do.

So **thank you to all the contributors** to SQLite, SQLiteNet and SQLite Net Extensions.  Frank Krueger,  Oystein Krog, Guillermo Gutiérrez Doral and all the rest.

However.... *Erm, what !*

I found the answer in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28408660/661584)

> Yes, it is normal. SQLite-Net Extensions is built on top of
>   SQLite-Net, that doesn't have support for foreign key constraints, so
>   there's no foreign key declared at the database layer.
>
> Using core SQLite-Net methods, the [ForeignKey] property is just an
>   integer property that doesn't have any kind of restriction, so you can
>   modify it at will without runtime errors.

i.e. the name of the **ForeignKey** attribute is **very misleading.** It's actually implemented as a simple Index

e.g. "Valuation_StockId" leaving you **without data integrity constraint** at the database level.

So you can (at the database level directly insert data that is non coherent, and not constrained) e.g. a Valuation referencing a Stock (via it's column StockId) that doesn't exist.

Not only that but nothing in the codebase stops you from doing the same.

So be careful folks the Attribute "ForeignKey" doesn't actually provide you with a Foreign Key relationship at all.

It is not a foreign key, and should not be named in a way to suggest it is - in my mind **this is really dangerous**.

Once again - **thank you to the people who released all their code** to the rest of us - and hopefully this might help someone else who like me is pulling their hair out trying to work out what they did wrong.

Comment: Every stated point is correct. I will update documentation to make it clearer. About changing the attribute name... suggestions are welcome, I couldn't find a better name myself

Comment: Appreciate that - and hugely appreciate the awesome code. Have been thinking about suitable name, will ponder and let you know if I come up with something better (it's not easy). Thanks. !

Comment: Off top of head - how about ForeignEntity or ForeignRow or RelatedEntity or RelatedRow ?